# Entering "ae" in EditText becomes æ automatically

Tags: android, ios, special-characters, android-edittext

I just inherited some android code and one of the first bugs I encountered was a weird EditText issue which when I type in the letters 'a' and 'e' in sequence, the EditText automatically merges them into the character 'æ'. Full xml declaration below:

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/editFirstname"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/profile_edittext_selector"
  android:ems="10"
  android:inputType="textCapSentences"
  android:paddingBottom="6dp"
  android:paddingLeft="15dp"
  android:paddingRight="5dp"
  android:paddingTop="5dp"
  android:textColor="#666666"
  android:textColorHint="#666666"
  android:textSize="12sp" >
</EditText>
```

I searched on the related Activity and Fragment using the xml, but I haven't found anything that can be blamed - no TextWatcher nor any routine trying to modify input or the charsequence inside the EditText. Input language is Use Default (set to English-US).

**The weird thing is, the same bug is filed in the iOS version of the app (different dev, also no clue as to why it's happening).**

Has anyone encountered this before?

edit:
drawable declaration, as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">\
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bgd_form_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bgd_form_selected" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bgd_form"/>
</selector>
```

edit2:

Additional info:
- Happens on all test devices: gs2, gs3, xperia z, nexus 4, galaxy ace

- as mentioned above: same bug filed on iOS
- **important: Server receives correct input when values are submitted (e.g "ae" is not transformed)** (this probably narrows it down to a Display issue)

Comment: Can show the code of `@drawable/profile_edittext_selector"` ?

Comment: I don't think that's relevant -- but please see edit.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your output.?

Comment: Could the problem here possibly lie in the attribute :ems, which might be doing some weird font-margin resizing? Try setting it to a bigger value and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: @ChrisZhang it's happening regardless of whatever is currently in the EditText. Even if it's empty before the text input. I'll try regardless and let you know in a bit.

Comment: @ChrisZhang no, it's still happening.

Comment: @JosephusVillarey Yeah sorry, it was a wild guess on my part with what source code was given. You might want to tell us some more about ANY and all code related to this specific EditText widget. Does this crop up on every device you're trying even with default settings?

Comment: if i could, i would. sadly, everything is there in the question. and yes, it happens on all the test devices (gs2, gs3, xperia z, nexus 4, galaxy ace) AND in iOS.

Comment: If you're targeting API level 9+, you can try removing diacritics by creating an input filter for the `EditText` and using a `Normalizer` for the æ in your input. For API level <9 you could make a regex for the special character. I think that the cause of this happening might be related to the language & locale settings. You could also try forcing a locale for the contents using the `String.format(Locale, String, Object...)` utility function when you set the contents back.

Comment: I've just seen there's a `EditText.setTextLocale(Locale)` method inherited from `TextView`. This simplifies things a bit as you can call `yourEditText.setTextLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)`. Can you, please, try it and let me know if it solves the issue? Btw, what's the language setting of the test phone that you are using? Is this happening for more than one language?

Comment: @lucian.pantelimon tried it, didn't work.

Comment: @JosephusVillarey Is there a custom Typeface used? I suspect a custom Font messing up the display of the characters.

Comment: input method editors (IMEs) do not have to honor all the settings in android:inputType. Those are suggestions or requests that you are making, not demands. try to do this programmatically might work "editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);"

Comment: @naveenprince i was not aware of that IME thing, thank you. will look into this suggestion first thing Monday.

Comment: Any chance you're using [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey&referrer=utm_source%3Dwebsite%26utm_medium%3Dgetswiftkey%26utm_campaign%3Dskx)? If you are, try the stock keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote:

> The weird thing is, the same bug is filed in the iOS version of the
>   app (different dev, also no clue as to why it's happening).

So I wonder if you added a [buggy version of the font Roboto](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=721719#c9) to the assets of the app. It contained a wrong ligature rule wich changed "ae" to "æ":

> ```
>   <Lookup index="1">
>     <LookupType value="4"/>
>     <LookupFlag value="0"/>
>     <!-- SubTableCount=1 -->
>     <LigatureSubst index="0" Format="1">
>       <LigatureSet glyph="a">
>         <Ligature components="e" glyph="ae"/>
>       </LigatureSet>
>       <LigatureSet glyph="f">
>         <Ligature components="i" glyph="fi"/>
>       </LigatureSet>
>     </LigatureSubst>
>   </Lookup>
> ```

It is already fixed, so your problem might be solved by updating the Roboto font in your app's assets.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. just "font" did not make sense, because I know the normal android Roboto does not have that bug. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I only have knowledge in ios, no android chops, sorry...
But the property of text which you are looking at here is called 'ligature'

From Wikipedia

> In writing and typography, a typographic ligature occurs where two or
>   more graphemes or letters are joined as a single glyph. Ligatures
>   usually replace consecutive characters sharing common components and
>   are part of a more general class of glyphs called "contextual forms",
>   where the specific shape of a letter depends on context such as
>   surrounding letters or proximity to the end of a line.

You might try a font which does not have the joined glyphs or there may be a property you can flip to turn ligature off for your text view in question. Interestingly

Also Wikipedia..

> The character Æ – lower case æ (in ancient times named æsc) when used
>   in the Danish, Norwegian, or Icelandic languages, or Old English, is
>   not a typographic ligature. It is a distinct letter—a vowel—and when
>   alphabetised, is given a different place in the alphabetic order. In
>   modern English orthography Æ is not considered an independent letter
>   but a spelling variant, for example: "encyclopædia" versus
>   "encyclopaedia" or "encyclopedia". Æ comes from Mediæval Latin, where
>   it was an optional ligature in some words, for example, "Æneas". It is
>   still found as a variant in English and French, but the trend has
>   recently been towards printing the A and E separately.[8] Similarly, Œ
>   and œ, while normally printed as ligatures in French, are wrongly
>   replaced by component letters if technical restrictions require it.

While this specific one is somehow not a ligature but a new vowel it is still generally found and governed in the ligature setting, eg in NSAttributedString in iOs you will affect this with the ligature attribute (the actual name of that enum i don't recall right now, NSAttributedString is kind of messy in that it uses different attribute names depending if you're using it with UIKit or with CoreText.)  Good luck, look into the android text docs on ligature

Comment: will look into this first thing on monday when i get back to work. thanks!

Comment: thanks Jef. it is an indeed an issue with the font i am using. Hartmut (answer below) pointed out that it is actually a bug in the actual font that I am using, not a "feature" of font.